# scroll an iframe from parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created two webpages, one contains the other in an iframe. I would like to scroll the embedded page from the parent page via javascript.

What I have tried so far:

1. `$('#go').scrollTop(200);`
2. `$('.footer').scrollTop(200);`
3. `var frame = document.getElementById('go');

   frame.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, 200);`

none of these have worked

the parent webpage html:

```
<html>
<body>
.
.
.
<div class="footer">
        <iframe id="go" src="go.html"></iframe>
    </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Both of these webpages are local files on the computer and I am using Google chrome with "--allow-file-access-from-files" flag.

How do I scroll the iframe to a certain position?

Comment: Do you know the content of "go.html"? can u simple focus on a required element within it?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I do know the contents of go.html but it contains another iframe on another domain so I cant access it. I did the iframe in an iframe to get around the same origin policy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works:

```
document.getElementById("go").contentWindow.setTimeout("this.scrollTo(0, 200);",1);
```

*Update*. Doh. Works in IE only, but I think there's something there.

*Update 2* This works universally:

```
document.getElementById("go").onload = function () { this.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, 200) };
```

You have to wait for iframe content to finish loading for scrollTo to work.

Comment: Yeah does not work in Chrome!! And I have also tried several variations with SetTimeout already with no luck :(.

Comment: Updated solution, please give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `window.postMessage` to send a message from your parent frame to the iframe, telling it to scroll. This takes you setting-up a `postMessage` script in the parent frame and a `receiveMessage` script in the iframe. It's the `receiveMessage` code that would actually scroll the iframe.

I've used this polyfill quite successfully: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Comment: The solution Yuriy provided is much easier to implement than this. Thanks for the plugin, will come in handy down the road!