# JavaScript scrolling website inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

My situation:

I have 2 websites:

---

```
      website 1
    ____________
   |            |
   |  website 2 | --- loading inside iframe
   |____________|
```

---

*Note:* Using different domains

Job:
In website 1, I have an array like:

```
var scrollTopPoints = [100, 900, 500, 300, 630];
```

I want to animate the points in the array in the `<iframe>` (so website 2 will be modified).

Error message I received:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://domain1.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://domain2.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I tried to fix the problem with `postMessage()`, like in in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406541/how-to-call-parent-window-javascript-function-inside-iframe).

But I still cant modify the `scrollTop` of the `<iframe>`.

---

Some test code (maybe not related)

Website 1 (including the iframe):

```
<script src="/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('iframe').on('scroll', function() {
            console.log('scrolled.');
        });

        function receiveMessage(event)
        {
            console.log(event.data);
        }

        addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

        $("iframe").contents().children().animate({ scrollTop: 100 }, 100);
    });
</script>
```

Website 2:

```
<div style="height:300px;background:#333;"></div>
<div style="height:300px;background:#555;"></div>
<div style="height:300px;background:#777;"></div>
<div style="height:300px;background:#999;"></div>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        parent.postMessage("This is a message", "*");
    });
</script>
```

Note that I used this as test code. I now see that:

1. I posted the wrong way (website 2 ---> website 1)
2. The part of the array is not defined here.

Another edit: The main problem is how to do animate the iframe with postmessage communication, because I can't access the iframe content directly when it has another domain.

---

Last edit: Problem solved

I used postmessage the wrong way. The code that did work for other visitors to this question:

Website 1 (parent)

```
<iframe id="frame" src="http://localhost/postmessage_test/" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script src="/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var scrollPoint = 100;

        var targetFrame = $('#frame')[0];
        targetFrame.onload = function() {
            targetFrame.contentWindow.postMessage(scrollPoint, '*');
        };
    });
</script>
```

Website 2 (child)

```
<div id="postMessage" style="height:30px;"></div>
    <div style="height:1500px;background:#333;"></div>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
            var eventer = window[eventMethod];
            var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

            eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
                var key = e.message ? "message" : "data";
                var data = e[key];

                window.scrollTo(0, data);
            },false);
        });
</script>
```

Thanks for all the help related to my post.

Comment: Can you show your PostMessage code?

Comment: I edited my question and added some test code. I don't think this will give you a better impression to what my problem is, but it's still better to include it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scroll an iframe from parent page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822608/scroll-an-iframe-from-parent-page)

Comment: I've got the problem with the error described in my question: "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin...", the question u mentioned doesn't encounter this problem. I guess I defined wrong communication with postmessage. (Edit: maybe not "wrong", but more the wrong way)

Comment: Is the iframe within the same domain? You have same domain policy restriction

Comment: It isn't in the same domain. That is why I tried postmessage as my solution to fix this problem, but without success.

Comment: I'm sorry. I used postmessage the wrong way (in my situation).

Comment: It looks like you solved your issue. To make it easier for others to find the answer, consider placing your solution as an answer and then marking it as accepted.